# How to reload UITableView after importing data?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView that takes its data from the app's sandbox, which is fulfilled by the FileManager's ".import" function. Basically, I have an "add" button that makes the "UIDocumentPickerViewController" popup and I am able to import files and the UITableView displays them.

My problem is that when I import a file, it is not displayed in the TableView, I have to quit the app and open it back for the file to be displayed.

I tried various things with "self.tableView.reloaddata()" and "tableView.reloaddata()" and nothing works, doesn't even show up in the console. I also tried to provide a "refresh" button, but it doesn't work either...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let dirPaths = FM.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let docsDir = dirPaths[0].path
        let importedfiles = try! FM.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: docsDir)


        self.importedfiles! = importedfiles as NSArray

    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return importedfiles.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
        withIdentifier: "cell",
        for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.titleLabel.text = importedfiles[indexPath.row] as? String

    return
```

The preferable thing would be that when I import a file, the TableView refreshes on its own. (The button thing was just a test)

Comment: `tableView.datasource` is set?

Comment: Do not use `NSArray`. Use a proper Swift array.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I hadn’t set the data source and I feel really dumb about this! Also, why use Array instead of NSArray? I changed it, but don’t know why this would be an issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to reload the data after new documents were picked.

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {


  ...

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loadFiles();
  }

  func loadFiles() {
    let dirPaths = FM.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let docsDir = dirPaths[0].path
    let importedfiles = try! FM.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: docsDir)

    self.importedfiles! = importedfiles as NSArray
  }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return importedfiles.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
        withIdentifier: "cell",
        for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.titleLabel.text = importedfiles[indexPath.row] as? String

    return cell;
  }

  ....
}


extension YourViewController: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
      self.loadFiles();
      self.tableView.reloadData();
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure to set the UIDocumentPickerDelegate: yourDocumentPicker.delegate = self

Comment: Thank you! First time asking a question here and I am not disappointed! Thanks so much!